# Select data between two dates in a SQLite DB using a ContentResolver?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, date

I have a DB in SQLite that saves the current date and time every time that the user inserts a new register. The date is stored in the db using the time string format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

So the problem is that I need select the registers that are in a range between two dates and sort the result from lower to higher. I'm using my own content provider so, How can I achive this?

This is my Query code:

```
                    final String[] projection = {Contrato.Columnas._ID,Contrato.Columnas.SISTOLICA,Contrato.Columnas.DIASTOLICA,Contrato.Columnas.PULSO};                       
                    final String orderBy = Contrato.Columnas.SISTOLICA + " DESC";
                    Cursor c = resolver.query(Contrato.URI_CONTENIDO_BASE,projection,null,null,orderBy);
```

Comment: A `ContentProvider` primarily is for publishing data to third-party apps. Why are you using one here?

Comment: Is a medical app that's gonna share reports of the Blood pressure measurements from the app of the patient to the Doctor app (and other app's of the Hospital system) thats why I'm using the ContentProvider, But if there is not a way to do this I think a rawQuery sould be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ContentProvider` is a façade. The meaning of any of the `ContentProvider`/`ContentResolver` API is up to you. So long as the client and the provider are in agreement over what parameters to things like `query()` mean, you can do whatever you want.

So, replace:

```
resolver.query(Contrato.URI_CONTENIDO_BASE,projection,null,null,orderBy)
```

with something like:

```
resolver.query(Contrato.URI_CONTENIDO_BASE,projection,Contrato.Columnas.SISTOLICA+">=? AND "+Contrato.Columnas.SISTOLICA+"<=?",args,orderBy)
```

where `args` are the two dates, in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format. Probably, you can pass that stuff along to SQLite without modification. Even if you do need to modify it... again, it's your code, so you can make it do whatever you want.